# Pass div content to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Example:

```
<div id="result"> some action </div>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Vote", "vote", new { id = Model.Catalog_Id, vote = result }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "location = location", Confirm = "Are you sure to vote?" })
```

Div result will change immediately when user selects a different radio button value. I want to pass latest radio button value to controller to insert data. Is that possible?

Comment: Not clear, what you're trying to do.

Comment: You need to use javascript to update the `href` attribute of the link. But you should be just using a form and submitting the form (never use a GET method to modify data in your database)

Comment: thx. problem solved. i can pass the div element myDivObj = document.getElementById("result"); Using ajax pass to controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ajax method call can solve the problem